# How to send multiple links to IDM (Internet download manager)?

Tags: command-line, command-line-arguments, system.diagnostics, download-manager, idm

I'm trying to send a couple of links to IDM like what it's extension does on browsers, but I don't know the command line related to it. All I know is that I can send a single link like this:

```
string idmpath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Download Manager\IDMan.exe";
string file = " /d "+"https://www.website.com/file.rar";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(idmpath, file );
```

But I don't want to send a single link. I'm going to send a couple of links like what IDM extension does in browsers:
[image]